# I want anchor tags to direct the div boxes on one page but is there a way so they can be centered after it bring you there?

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, anchor

I am trying to have these divs centered on the screen after you click them but they do not. Sometimes they get hidden behind my fixed navbar up top and the biggest issue is the last box doesn't show at all just the first link of the anchored text at the very bottom of the browswer. I am screwed? How would I make this work? here is my code...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AJAR Designs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ajarcss.css">



<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.videoBG-master/assets/jquery-1.5.1.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.videoBG-master/jquery.videoBG.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.videoBG-master/assets/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="df_smooth_scroll/smooth.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-7654450-4']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async =  true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +  '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</script>

</head>

<body id="body">
<div id="navbarcontainer"> 
<ul>
<li id="navbuttons"><a id="navdecorations" href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
<li id="navbuttons"><a id="navdecorations" href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
<li id="navbuttons"><a id="navdecorations" href="#Bio">Bio</a></li>
<li id="contactbutton"><a id="navdecorations" href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<div id="home"></div>
<div id="portfolio"><a name="Portfolio"></a>Portfolio</div>
<div id="bio"><a name="Bio"></a>Bio</div>
<div id="contact"><a name="Contact"></a>Contact</div>



</body>

</html>
```

and my css...

```
html {
overflow-x: hidden
}

#navbarcontainer
{   background-color: #000000;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height:50px;
float: left;
left: 0%;
float:left;
text-align:center;
margin-top: 0px;
top: 0px;
text-align:left;
padding-top: 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
font-family:Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-  serif;
font-size:130%;
z-index:9999;

}

#navbuttons
{
border-left: thin solid #A6A6A6; border-left-width:1px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-left:4px;
a:text-decoration:none;
position:relative;
padding-top:13px;
padding-bottom:13px;}



ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding-top:13px;
display: inline-block;
position:relative;
width:400px;
}

li
{
display:inline;

}

#home
{
height:500px;
width:80%;
position:relative;
clear:both;
background-color:#000000;
margin:0 auto;
top:60px;
overflow:hidden;
border:solid thick;
border-color:#555454;
border-radius:10px;
padding:10px;


}

#portfolio
{
height:500px;
width:80%;
position:relative;
clear:both;
background-color:#000000;
margin:0 auto;
top:120px;
overflow:hidden;
border:solid thick;
border-color:#555454;
border-radius:10px;
padding:50px;
color:white;
}

#bio
{
height:500px;
width:80%;
position:relative;
clear:both;
background-color:#000000;
margin:0 auto;
top:180px;
overflow:hidden;
border:solid thick;
border-color:#555454;
border-radius:10px;
padding:50px;
color:white;

}

#contact
{
height:500px;
width:80%;
position:relative;
clear:both;
background-color:#000000;
margin:0 auto;
top:240px;
overflow:hidden;
border:solid thick;
border-color:#555454;
border-radius:10px;
padding:50px;
color:white;


}






p
{color:#FFFFFF;}


#navdecorations
{text-decoration:none;}

#contactbutton
{
border-right: thin solid #A6A6A6; border-left-width:1px;
border-left: thin solid #A6A6A6; border-left-width:1px;
padding-right:4px;
padding-left:4px;
a:text-decoration:none;
position:relative;
padding-top:13px;
padding-bottom:13px;
}

a:link { color: white }
a:visited { color:white }
a:hover { color:#A2F07E }
a:active { color: red }
```

Comment: You should be more concrete and show only the relevant code.

Comment: Which divs in that code are you talking about, and how are you trying to center them upon click?

Comment: the home portfolio bio and contact are the ones. sorry I am a newb here and the js doesnt matter thats something else. just the css and the anchor tags

Comment: #home #portfolio #bio #contact

Comment: In JS FIDDLE the links work fine and direct to the appropriate div centered on the screen. However, in chrome or firefox it does not work this way and I dont know why :( Its stressing  me out a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmq3G/2/)

You just add a class to your anchors, and add an a.anchor definition to your CSS (I added it to the bottom of the CSS).

```
a.anchor{display: block; position: relative; top: -150px; visibility: hidden;}
```

Comment: Thank. This seems correct! I will try it out in between work ;) lol

Comment: no it didnt work. I want it so when you click the anchor link it directs you to the CENTER of the div so its centered on the screen. Is this possible?

Comment: its weird because it works when the window is not maximized but once the browser is maximized when I click contact (the last one) it never navigates there in the center) This is so annoying I dont understand how to do this. Is it possible?